# How to drop a LISTEN port in CentOS7? the port dose not seem to binding to any process

Tags: port, centos7, kill-process, netstat, firewalld

I would like to drop a port which is currently in state LISTEN.

This is when I type `netstat -anp | grep LISTEN | grep 8080`.

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

as you can see, there is no process ID.

I have also tried `fuser -n 8080 tcp` and `fuser 8080/tcp`, but those commands print nothing.

How could drop the port safely? - My original plan was find pid and command `kill`, but is there any safer way to stop a port?

Thanks.

Comment: `lsof -i:8080` also prints nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out. It was caused by user.
If I try with user `root`. It prints the pid

```
[iceman ~]$ sudo netstat -anp | grep 8080
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      47950/uni***
```